# View code generation readiness issues , c code generation from Matlab function

Tags: matlab-coder

I got some issues while generate the 'C' Code from Matlab Function.Issue like this "Unsupported MATLAB Function calls" & "Code generation tools may fail unless the issues listed below are fixed". The following basic MATLAB comments are not supported while generate the C code 1.input, 2.cell2mat, 3.xlsread, etc.

So can you guys please tell instead of these comments.?

Thanks MuruganView code generation readiness issues , c code generation from Matlab function

Answer (score 1):

There are certain MATLAB functions and features that are not yet supported for C/C++ code generation. This is the reason why the code generation readiness tool is flagging all these issues. Below is the complete list of functions supported for code generation

http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation--alphabetical-list.html

Here is the list of all MATLAB language features supported for code generation
http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/matlab-language-features-supported-for-code-generation.html

Hope this helps.